# Eclipse wanting to run wrong class

Tags: java, eclipse

I am a new java developer out here, and ive come across this weird thing, that eclipse still thinks my main class is called illuminati (just randomly wrote something..)
here is a screenshot of the error i get:
[image]

so what the problem is, basicly eclipse cant find the mainclass even though i changed the name..
and i dont know how to configure it that the class is gone (or changed name)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try a clean build?

Comment: Correct the import1.java

Comment: first there is no screenshot :) 2nd if I remember correctly you can right click the class and click run

Comment: You haven't explained how you're trying to run the class. If you're using the old run configuration, then yes - it will fail. So right-click on the class and select "Run As..." and then you'll create a new run configuration.

Comment: And don't name your classes that way such as "MAIN". You'd better name your classes, interfaces, methods, etc based on Java Naming Conventions. Take a look at http://www.iwombat.com/standards/JavaStyleGuide.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select the class you want to run (`MAIN`), then click the green-arrow-in-circle Run icon, and select "Run As -> Java Application".

If you rename the class and you didn't let Eclipse rename the run configuration, then you can simply create a new run configuration for the new class.